# Change sprite in Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class sort of managing a game's user interface.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
    ArrayList sprites;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        sprites = new ArrayList();
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("bettle", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("donut", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("icecream", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("letter", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("paper", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("papercup", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("puzzle", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("sock", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("tag", typeof(Sprite)));
        sprites.Add(Resources.Load("underwear", typeof(Sprite)));

        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                GameObject go = Resources.Load("ItemPrefab") as GameObject;
                go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.Count)] as Sprite;
                float fx = -2 + 1f * x;
                float fy = -2 + 1f * y;
                go.transform.position = new Vector3(fx, fy, 0);

                Instantiate(go);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the above codes to instantiate a Prefab for multiple times on screen. The Prefab contains a `SpriteRenderer`, which by default the sprite is set to "tag" (just a name).

As you can see above, I get a random sprite from the `ArrayList` and set the `SpriteRenderer`'s sprite value. But on screen, the sprite remains "tag".

What did I miss?

Note:

- the sprites in the `ArrayList` are loaded successfully
- no error is shown in runtime / compile time

Answer (score 1):

When you **Instantiate** you get a new copy of the prefab you're passing.

Try setting the sprite on the object that is return by Instantiate and not on the prefab you're loading.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
   for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        GameObject go = Resources.Load("ItemPrefab") as GameObject;

        go = Instantiate(go) as GameObject;

        go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.Count)] as Sprite;
        float fx = -2 + 1f * x;
        float fy = -2 + 1f * y;
        go.transform.position = new Vector3(fx, fy, 0);
    }
}
```

What I've did is changing the position on the object returned by Instantiate.

Comment: Thanks. However, the displaying GameObjects on screen are still look like "tags", though I see the values of sprite is changed to different sprite other than "tags".